# Calling data from two different mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am beginner for coding.

I have a table which I need data from two different mysql database tables.

Here is so far;

```
$query = "SELECT t.*, DATE_FORMAT(t.created, '%e %b %Y') AS payment_date, u.username, u.email FROM prcb_transactions t,  prcb_users u WHERE t.user_id=u.user_id $filter_by ORDER BY $rrorder $rorder LIMIT $from, $results_per_page";
        $result = smart_mysql_query($query);
        $total_on_page = mysql_num_rows($result);

<?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $cc++; ?>
                  <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $row['username']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['title']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['transaction_amount']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
```

The 'title' column is on another table called prcb_retailers but do nt know how to mention for this table in $query. Can anybody spark my mind?

Comment: what's the name of the table where you want the title column?

Comment: @circle73 it will be displayed on the site so I will not insert the 'title' to a new table. 'title' is located in db table called "prcb_retailers"

Comment: [www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Well, you already joined two tables, what's the problem joining another one?

Answer (score 0):

I believe JOINS will do it for you, but please make sure you are using your indexes correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with the next query:

```
$query="
SELECT
   t.*,
   DATE_FORMAT(t.created, '%e %b %Y') AS payment_date,
   u.username,
   u.email,
   r.*
FROM
   prcb_transactions t,
   prcb_users u,
   prcb_retailers r
WHERE
   r.id=t.retailer_id and
   t.user_id=u.user_id
   $filter_by
ORDER BY
   $rrorder $rorder
LIMIT $from, $results_per_page
";
```

I guessed the `r.id=t.retailer_id` part... Probably you have to change the field names to the real ones...

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve the excepted result needs to mention the column 'title' in the selection list. Hope 'Title' field is available in table 'prcb_users' then use column 'u.title'